# ifupdown not recognizing interface, but interface is working?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

So, all of a sudden `ifup` and `ifdown` does not seem to work for me.

I'm running Debian Jessie on a VM and I properly connect my wifi dongle to it and everything has worked perfect until some time last week.

Whenever I run `ifdown wlan0` I get the error message

> ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured

and when I run `ifup wlan0` I get the error message

> wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start run-parts:
>   /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
>   Failed to bring up wlan0.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the line `auto wlan0` from the file `/etc/network/interfaces`